# Call python script from another python script

Tags: python

I have two scripts

**script_1.py**

```
import sys
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import isleap

count = sys.argv[1]
state = sys.argv[2]

f = open("myfile_c_"+count+".xml", 'a')
f.write("<state >"+state+"state "+"\n")
f.close()
```

it creates files (copies of a file) according to the input count variable

**script_2.py**

```
import random
import subprocess
import decimal
import string
import sys
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import isleap

copy = int(sys.argv[1])
count = 0

state = random.choices( ["FeeSimple","Leasehold","Other"], weights=(80, 15, 5), k=copy)


while (count < copy):      
exec(open("script_1.py count state[int(count]").read()) // should call the first script and enter the arguments
```

any idea how to call the first script from the second script and enter the arguments in the while loop ?

Answer (score 0):

in top of script_2.py put the line below,else, you have another variable in your script_2.py called count so change one of them into another name to avoid bug.

```
from script_1 import count
```